# An equality for expectation of the non-negative random variable

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

I once read the following inequality

[image]

Is there any specific name for this inequality? And, how to prove it?

Comment: Use Fubini. Then, pause. Then, ask yourself why the argument doesn't work, in general, if $X$ can take both positive and negative values.

Comment: See discussion of the result [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18438/does-a-univariate-random-variables-mean-always-equal-the-integral-of-its-quanti) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative). I've only heard it expressed as 'the expectation is the integral of the survival function' ... rather than with any particular name.

Comment: Incidentally, for continuous random variables, you can show it in two lines using integration by parts.