# References: Tail of the inverse cdf

Tags: references, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function, moments

I am almost sure I have already seen the following result in statistics but I can't remember where.

> If $X$ is a positive random variable and $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$ then $\varepsilon F^{-1}(1-\varepsilon) \to 0$ when $\varepsilon\to 0^+$, where $F$ is the cdf of $X$.
>
> This is easy to see geometrically by using the equality $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int 1-F$ and by considering a horizontal cut at $\varepsilon$ of the area under the curve of the integrand $1-F$.

Do you know a reference for this result and whether it has a name ?

Comment: The "more generally" is a straightforward application of integration by parts.  That scarcely needs a reference!

Comment: @whuber I'm asking for a reference about the first result too.

Comment: You might have seen it, or at least something very much like it, at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18438.  That result is due to a substitution in the integral, which again is so basic one would not expect it to have been especially noted in the literature or given some special name.

Comment: @whuber I don't see $\epsilon F^{-1}(1-\epsilon) \to 0$ in your link. Moreover the result I mention is true for a discrete $F$ too (by taking $g$ to be a sequence and replacing $\int$ with $\sum$ in the more general statement). The first result is even true for a general $F$, I think.

Comment: @whuber Sorry your link adresses the case of the general $F$ too. In fact, are you meaning that $\epsilon F^{-1}(1-\epsilon) \to 0$ is a direct consequence of $E(X)=\int F^{-1}$ ?

Comment: I do beleive that to be true, but you must assume the expectation exists. When the expectation exists, it follows that for some $\gamma>1,C>0,N$, for all $x>N$, that $P(X>x)\le \frac{C}{\gamma-1}x^{1-\gamma}$, and that should be enough for a proof.

Comment: Yes, it's a direct consequence requiring no assumptions beyond integrability of $F^{-1}$ on $[1-\epsilon,1-\delta)$ for all $0\lt\delta\lt\epsilon$ and the fact that $F^{-1}$ does not decrease on these intervals.

Comment: @whuber FYI, I have edited my post to replace the more general result by a more general one I am able to get.

Comment: As written, the statement is strange and I don't think it says what you intend it to.  The right hand side is an integral with random endpoint, which could be any positive number, while the left hand side is an integral on a subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @whuber $F^{-1}$ takes its values in the support of $X$, not in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks--I was misreading the upper endpoint as "$F(1-\epsilon)$" for some reason, even though you never wrote that.  Sorry to create any confusion... .

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the confusion too. My new statement of the general result was a direct application of the first one. I have deleted it now.

Comment: @whuber FYI, see here the origin of my thoughts about the "more general result": http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281595/38217

Comment: I believe that this could be used without any reference provided it is
stated in more classical terms. Roughly speaking, this is: $x\,\bar{F}(x) \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$ with $\bar{F} := 1 - F$, a direct
consequence of: $x \,\text{Pr}\{ X > x \} \leq \mathbb{E}[X \,1_{\{X >
x\}}]$ and of dominated convergence. A little work is needed to 
get the statement for the (left continuous) inverse $F^{-1}$ in the 
general case where $F$ can have steps.

Answer (score 2):

To handle the "little work" suggested by Yves in the comments, **geometry suggests a rigorous and fully general proof.**

If you like, you may replace all references to areas by integrals and references to "arbitrary" by the usual epsilon-delta arguments.  The translation is easy.

**To set up the picture,** let $G$ be the survival function

$$G(x) = 1-F(x) = \Pr(X \gt x).$$

[image: Figure]

The figure plots a part of $G$. (Notice the jump in the graph: this particular distribution is not continuous.) A large threshold $T$ is shown and a tiny probability $\epsilon \le G(T)$ has been selected (so that $G^{-1}(\epsilon)\ge T$).

**We're ready to go:** the value we're interested in, $\epsilon F^{-1}(1-\epsilon) = \epsilon G^{-1}(\epsilon)$ (the one we want to show converges to zero), is the area of the white rectangle with height $\epsilon$ and base from $x=0$ to $x= G^{-1}(\epsilon)$.  Let's relate this area to the expectation of $F$, because the only assumption available to us is that this expectation exists and is finite.

The positive part $E_{+}$ of the expectation $\mathbb{E}_F(X)$ is the area under the survival curve (from $0$ to $\infty$):

$$\mathbb{E}_F(X) = E_{+}-E_{-} = \int_0^\infty G(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x) dx.$$

Because $E_{+}$ must be finite (for otherwise the expectation itself would not exist and be finite), we may pick $T$ so large that the area under $G$ between $0$ and $T$ accounts for all, or nearly all, of $E_{+}$.

All the pieces are now in place: the graph of $G$, the threshold $T$, the small height $\epsilon$, and the right-hand endpoint $G^{-1}(\epsilon)$ suggest a dissection of $E_{+}$ into areas we can analyze:

- As $\epsilon$ goes to zero from above, the area of the white rectangle with base $0\le x \lt T$ shrinks to zero, because $T$ remains constant.  (*This is why $T$ was introduced; it's the key idea to this demonstration.*)
- The blue area can be made as close to $E_{+}$ as you might like, by starting with a suitably large $T$ and then choosing small $\epsilon$.
- Consequently, the area left over--which clearly is no greater than the white rectangle with base from $x=T$ to $x=G^{-1}(\epsilon)$--can be made arbitrarily small.  (In other words, just ignore the red and gold areas.)

**We have thereby broken $\epsilon G^{-1}(\epsilon)$ into two pieces whose areas both converge to zero.**  Thus,  $\epsilon G^{-1}(\epsilon)\to 0$, *QED.*